# How to add multiple values to my field using ForeignKey (Django models)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    category  = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Rigth now my Video objects can only have 1 category selected. I 'd like to be able to have multiple categories for my category field. Is this possible using ForeignKey?

i.e

TABLE VIDEO:

Video1.category = "drama", "terror"

TABLE CATEGORY:

Category1.category = "drama"

Category2.category = "terror"

Comment: use  [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)  instead of `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the Video model like this will do the trick:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='video/%y")
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I was displaying my object information in the admin panel with this class in my `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(Video)
class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('video', 'category')
```

When I changed my `ForeignKey` to `ManyToManyField` I got this error:

> <class 'portfolio.admin.VideoAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of
> 'list_display[8]' must not be a ManyToManyField.

This was because lists are not supported by `list_display`, in order to fix that I created a method inside my Video class to return a string that contains the list elements. And replaced the field name in `list_display` to the method name.

Final code:

`models.py`

```
class Video(models.Model):
        video = models.FileField(upload_to='video/%y")
        category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
        
        def get_categories(self):
                return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.category.all()])

class Category(models.Model):
        category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`Admin.py`

```
@admin.register(Video)
class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('video', 'get_categories')

admin.site.register(Category)
```